# ASP.NET+C#+XML application as TransferLayer,DataLayer,BusinessLayer and UserInterface arhitecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2010

I was employed 1 week ago at a company which creates CAD products.

During the training (some days) I studied C# language and ASP.NET.

Yesterday, I received an application with TL, DL, BL, and UI arhitecture from project manager.

I have a XML file like as:

```
<parent>
<Categories name="something1">
<link url="link1" name="name1" description="descr1"/>
<link url="link2" name="name2" description="descr2"/>
...
</Categories>
<Categories name="something2">
<link url="link1" name="name11" description="descr11"/>
<link url="link2" name="name21" description="descr21"/>
...
</Categories>
...
</parent>
```

After that, project manager explained me how to extract XML information (Categories and Links) using TL, DL, BL, and UI arhitecture. But I don't understand good.

I will make a summary about what I understood.
He said (P.Manager) that in TransferLayer I have to create two classes: one for Links and other for Categories.
So, in Link class I will use setter and getter.
I wrote like this in C#:

```
public class Links
{
   private string url_link;
   private string name_link;
   private string desc_link;

   public string Url_Linkz
   {
   get { return url_link;}
   set { url_link = value;}
   }

   public string Name_Linkz
   {
   get { return name_link;}
   set { name_link = value;}
   }

   public string Descr_Linkz
   {
   get { return descr_link;}
   set { descr_link = value;}
   }
}
```

Ok until here (I hope that I wrote correctly).
Now, he told me about Categories class which has Name property (with setter and getter) and List of links (this object for every link, here I don't know how) which takes from Link class.

In DataLayer, in UrlStorage class, I have to take a list of categories from Categories class.

Be careful, in TL and DL layer, I have not to use XML function or any operation over XML file.

in BL layer I will use methods which operate over XML file (Add node, remove node, etc.) and get a list of categories.

in UI, I will implement a TreeView object to show categories with their links.

I don't need the other code but I need a complete project which has all four layers arhitecture to understand better. No definitions just examples because I will understand better with examples. Of course, I will create some more examples to know very good.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The TL (Transfer Layer) will contain what are called DTOs (Data Transfer Objects). The purpose of the DTOs is to provide a simple means from transferring data from one system (or layer) to another. In your case, the Link and Categories classes you mentioned would be considered DTOs (potentially named LinkDto and CategoriesDto). They are responsible for containing the data when going to and from the BL (Business Layer, or Data Layer in other instances).

Here's an example of your DTO classes to get you started (these aren't 100% correct).

```
public class LinkDto
{
    [XmlAttribute("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryDto
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public List<Link> Links { get; set; }
}
```

At this point I'd suggest doing a bit of reading on [XmlSerialization](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813). It is one method you can use to read/save xml files to and from .NET.

Once you're DTO classes are set up properly, your Business Layer classes will generally consume these in some way.

Edit: Moved Dto loading into Data Layer, replaced with Data Layer call

```
namespace BusinessLayer
{
     public class Category
    {
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public List<Link> Links { get; set; }

         public static Category GetAll()
         {
             return DataLayer.GetAllCategories();
         }
    }  

    public class Link
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

}

**UPDATE**
Per your requirements, your serialization logic and the Load methods shown above could be moved into your Data Layer.  Here's an example of what you could use for serialization:

```
public static string Serialize<t>(t obj)
{
    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(t));
        formatter.Serialize(writer, obj);

        return writer.ToString();
    }
}

public static t Deserialize<t>(string xml)
{
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(t));
        return (t)formatter.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

In your UI, you'll be interacting with the Business Layer exclusively. That is why the GetAll method is exposed on the Category class. Since your data doesn't appear to be hierarchical, I wouldn't recommomend the TreeView control, but rather a set of nested repeaters.

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCategories" OnItemDataBound="rptCategories_ItemDatabound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h2>Category: <%#Eval("Name") %></h2>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptLinks">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="<%#Eval("url") %>" title="<%#Eval("Description") %>"><%#Eval("Name") %></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

With a code behind similar to:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        rptCategories.DataSource = Category.GetAll();
        rptCategories.DataBind();
    }

}

protected void rptCategories_ItemDatabound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) {

        var repeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptLinks");
        var category = (Category)e.Item.DataItem;

        repeater.DataSource = category.Links;
        repeater.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I used System.Xml.Serialization.XMLAttribute("url")

Comment: In fact, I have to declare LinkDto and CategoriesDto in TransferLayer...In DataLayer I have a class called URLStorage which works with XML file and get a list of categories. How to use these class for TreeView in UserInterface layer ? Please...Thank you

Comment: unknown method GetAllCategories();

Comment: This code is provided as an example, not as a verbatim application. There is more than enough sound information here to get you started which is what you were requesting.